# why when rewrote web app to multi module style a have "Error instantiating servlet class [servlet.LoginServlet]"

Tags: java, web, tomcat, servlets

I understand that there are a lot of similar questions, but i can't find where is my problem. So, my question is: When I had all my code in src package of my project and when I started my tomcat app all was good, but when I rewrote my app to multi module architecture I got error. Maybe I should change some paths or so on?  In root target web.xml it gives me:

my web.xml: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8wRE.png

this is error screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j1Ac.png

my target/web.xml: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oknrq.png

Building with **mvn clean package** is ok.

```
web.xml
```

````
   
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <display-name>MyWebApp</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.WelcomeServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CustomerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.CustomerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.LogoutServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CustomerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/customers</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app> ```

Thanks for attention.
````

Comment: Please paste the code fragment

Comment: Thanks for your attention. What exactly code part?

Comment: The `web.xml` source code could be helpful

Comment: I added web.xml from my-new-web-app-servlet/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

Answer (score 0):

So, my solution was to change artifact. When I change the location of my tomcat webserver, I should change artifact

Answer (score -1):

The Maven dependencies of IntelliJ are not up to date, see the "m"-button. This might be the cause of the problem.
Click on the "m"-button with "turning arrows" in the top right corner of your editor window.

mvn and IntelliJ manage dependencies independently.

Comment: What's the problem with my answer for having it downvoted? OK, it did not solve your problem. But I could have been the answer. Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation points do anything else then writing an answer, e.g. I'm not able to add comments to your question.

Comment: I didn't downvote for your answer, as you can see my question is downvoted also :)